# TFS2013 changes in the build template don't have any effect

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I changed a TFS2013 build template and the changes don't take any effect, even if I force an exception. The changes are properly checked-in. New defined arguments are visible in the logs, but **none of the newly added additional activities are executed, neither visible in the logs**.

**[update]**

I didn't add any custom activities. I just added a new **MSBuild** activity just after the main build loop to build a WIX project. I also added some conditions to check whether there really is a WiX project to build or whether the given project exists.

**[/update]**

What could be a reason for that?

Thanks,
Juergen

Comment: What kind of changes have you made? Can you post an example activity and the log output that you get?

Comment: Please make sure there are not conflicts with your custom activities and the original activities. If there is, the build may not execute the one. And also could you provide more detailed info?

Comment: I didn't add any custom activities. I just added a new MSBuild activity just after the main build loop to build a WIX project. 
I also added some conditions to check whether there really is a WiX project to build or whether the given project exists. 
The problem is, there is no log output of the added activity or the conditions. It should output at least a false condition in the diagnostic output.

Comment: There are 2 MSBuild Steps... One for clean and one for Build, did you add it to the right one.

Comment: Hi @DaveShaw, that's it. Many thanks :) What a stupid mistake... That's the reason why I don't like this huge XAML based TFS templates.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XAML, there are 2 places where MSBuild is called, one for the "Clean" and one for the "Build".

If you add the activities to the just Clean activity, you won't see them run on the build. I usually just add my custom MSBuild stuff into both.